# $_SESSION function is not grabbing the session variable

Tags: php, html, apache, xampp, session-variables

When using the `$_SESSION` function it is not grabbing the session variable. I am not getting any error popup on screen but when I check the server error logs  I am getting an

> undefined index

Also when I add print_r($_SESSION); to the top of my code but still inside php tags all of my html on the page disappears

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM personalads WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_NUM);
$u = $row[1];
$age = $row[2];
$university = $row[3];
$headline = $row[4];
$message = $row[5];
$img = $row[6];
$picture = "";
if($img != NULL){
$picture = '<img class="adpicture" src="user/'.$u.'/'.$img.'">';
}
```

and

```
$PM = '<div class="adrespond">';
$PM .= '<form onclick="return false;" name="pmForm" id="pmForm" method="post">';
$PM .= '<br><center>Send a message to the poster</center><br>';
$PM .= '<textarea name="pmTextArea" id="pmTextArea" rows="4" cols="30"></textarea>';
$PM .= '<input name="pm_sender_id" id="pm_sender_id" type="hidden" value="'.$_SESSION["userid"].'" />';
$PM .= '<input name="pm_sender_name" id="pm_sender_name" type="hidden" value="'.$_SESSION["username"].'" />';
$PM .= '<input name="pm_rec_name" id="pm_rec_name" type="hidden" value="'.$u.'" />';
$PM .= '<span id="PMStatus" style="color:#F00;"></span><br />';
$PM .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;<center><button name="pmSubmit" id="pmSubmit" onclick="sendPM()" >Send Message</button></center>';
$PM .= '<span id="status"></span>';
$PM .= '</div>';
```

when I add print_r($_SESSION) and print_r($_GET)(second array is from $_GET) my html on the webpage disappears, the output of that function is

```
Array ( [userid] => 1 [username] => jbird [password] => ********
[mysex] => male [lookingfor] => female [university] => Brock ) Array ( [id] => 14 )
```

no error is printed on the webpage but when I check the error log I see this

```
[18-Jul-2015 23:40:47 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\Website\adcontent.php on line 7

[18-Jul-2015 23:40:47 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: userid in C:\xampp\htdocs\Website\adcontent.php on line 26

[18-Jul-2015 23:40:47 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\Website\adcontent.php on line 27
```

line 7 is $id = $_GET["id"]; and line 26 and 27 are where I use the $_SESSION function, im using xampp apache server, anyone have any idea whats going on here its really starting to p me off. Thanks

all of adcontent.php

```
<?php
include_once("check_login_status.php");
print_r($_SESSION);
print_r($_GET);
?>
<?php
$id = $_GET["id"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM personalads WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_NUM);
$u = $row[1];
$age = $row[2];
$university = $row[3];
$headline = $row[4];
$message = $row[5];
$img = $row[6];
$picture = "";
if($img != NULL){
$picture = '<img class="adpicture" src="user/'.$u.'/'.$img.'">';
}

    $PM = '<div class="adrespond">';
    $PM .= '<form onclick="return false;" name="pmForm" id="pmForm" method="post">';
    $PM .= '<br><center>Send a message to the poster</center><br>';
    $PM .= '<textarea name="pmTextArea" id="pmTextArea" rows="4" cols="30"></textarea>';
    $PM .= '<input name="pm_sender_id" id="pm_sender_id" type="hidden" value="'.$_SESSION["userid"].'" />';
    $PM .= '<input name="pm_sender_name" id="pm_sender_name" type="hidden" value="'.$_SESSION["username"].'" />';
    $PM .= '<input name="pm_rec_name" id="pm_rec_name" type="hidden" value="'.$u.'" />';
    $PM .= '<span id="PMStatus" style="color:#F00;"></span><br />';
    $PM .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;<center><button name="pmSubmit" id="pmSubmit" onclick="sendPM()" >Send Message</button></center>';
    $PM .= '<span id="status"></span>';
    $PM .= '</div>';

// PHP FOR SENDING PRIVATE MESSAGES
if(isset($_POST["sendername"])){
    $pmTA = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['pmTextArea']);
    $sname = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9 ]#i', '', $_POST['sendername']);
    $rname = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9 ]#i', '', $_POST['recName']);
    $number = "1";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO privatemessages (to_user, from_user, time_sent, message) VALUES ('$rname','$sname',now(),'$pmTA')";
    header("location: personalspage.php");
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql) or die("Its not working");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="jquery-2.1.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="ajax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function sendPM() {
      var pmTextArea = _("pmTextArea").value;
      var sendername = _("pm_sender_name").value;
      var recName = _("pm_rec_name").value;
      var status = _("status");
      if (pmTextArea == "") {
           status.innerHTML("Please type in your message.");
      } else {
           var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "adcontent.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"); 
           window.location = "adcontent.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>";      
      }
       ajax.send("pmTextArea="+pmTextArea+"&sendername="+sendername+"&recName="+recName);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<?php include_once("template_pageTop.php"); ?>
<div>
<div class="adcontent">
    <div class="adcontentpicture">
        <?php echo $picture; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="adcontenttext">
        <b>Age:</b><?php echo $age; ?><br><br>
        <?php echo $university; ?> University <br><br>
        <?php echo $headline; ?><br><hr>
        <?php echo $message; ?><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <hr><?php //echo $PM; ?>
        <div class="adrespond">
        <form onclick="return false;" name="pmForm" id="pmForm" method="post">
        <br><center>Send a message to the poster</center><br>
        <textarea name="pmTextArea" id="pmTextArea" rows="4" cols="30"></textarea>
        <input name="pm_sender_id" id="pm_sender_id" type="hidden" value="'.$_SESSION['userid'].'" />
        <input name="pm_sender_name" id="pm_sender_name" type="hidden" value="'.$_SESSION['username'].'" />
        <input name="pm_rec_name" id="pm_rec_name" type="hidden" value="'.$u.'" />
        <span id="PMStatus" style="color:#F00;"></span><br />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;<center><button name="pmSubmit" id="pmSubmit" onclick="sendPM()" >Send Message</button></center>
        <span id="status"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

when logging in the session variable are set

Comment: Do you mean you put some value into $_SESSION variable and the value disappears?

Comment: The error message says everything you need to fix the problem. At the time of execution, the index is not defined. In the snippet(s) you provided us, you actually never defined them. If you did it at a different place in your code, please provide the relevant code part. Also, you're trying to retrieve a GET variable in your PHP code, but submitting the form via `method="post"`.

Comment: @Ondřej Šotek no the value is there but when I use $_SESSION function to retrieve it I get an undefined index error

Comment: @FoxRider look at the code snippet where i show what the print_r($_SESSION) and print_r($_GET) outputs the first array is from session function and second array is from get function, the values are there but the functions are not retrieving them properly

Comment: You provided the output, but not the place where you put it, and we don't know what happens before and after the `print_r`. That makes it impossible for us to reproduce it.

Comment: Could you just show us the whole code of your `adcontent.php` file ?

Comment: its kind of long but here thanks for helping though guys i really do appreciate it @akmozo

Comment: @FoxRider I posted all the code from adcontent.php

Comment: @JeremySills, allow me to join the party, where is your `<?php session_start();?>` and in your code i can't see you load any variable to `$_SESSION`

Comment: @JeremySills Could you tell us how did you opened the file `adcontent.php`   when you got the errors ? I think that you did directly in the browser and when trying with the `print_r()`, you did it correctly ( via another page ).

Comment: @shehary the session variables are set in a different file and they are working if you understand print_r function than you'll that ive posted the output and its dislay the session and get variables which means they are there

Comment: @akmozo the file is opened from another page by clicking a link if thats what your asking

Comment: @JeremySills In both cases ?

Comment: @JeremySills, oh I'm sorry, i don't understand the print_r function, so i better leave you expert guys resolving the problem, peace :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't really make out the source of your problem, but here are some things I noticed when reviewing your code:

- Am I guessing right that `adcontent.php` submits form data to itself? If so, you should explicitly check that the user has actually submitted the form, for instance via [`isset`](http://php.net/isset). Though, better practice would be to outsource the handling of the AJAX request into a separate file.
- Are you actually initialising the session via [`session_start`](http://php.net/session-start)? This is necessary to access session variables.

Also, you should always validate data that comes from the user. In your example, you should validate or [type cast](http://php.net/types.type-juggling#language.types.typecasting) `$_GET['id']` to an integer before passing it to your database.

Comment: yea form data is submitted to itself, I had the isset function there before but thought it was the problem so I took it out, in my login.php file the session is started 100% i know that, data validation I still need to do lol I was just leaving it until I could finger this out, trying to strip everything down to make it as simple as possibe to figure out the problem, could it have something to do with the server and how it processes the data recieved(im using xampp apache)